# Regular expression for specific email address format in a validation rule

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I have a regular expression which requires emails to be in firstname.lastname@email.com format.

I want to tweak to be firstname.lastname@email.com OR firstname.i.lastname@email.com where 'i' would be the middle initial of the user.

```
NOT(REGEX(Recipients__c, '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@(email.com)+([,]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@(email.com))*' ))
```

Comment: Can first and last names contain numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The regex you want is:

```
[A-Za-z]+\.([A-Za-z]+\.)?[A-Za-z]+@email\.com
```

- `[A-Za-z]+\.`: Match at least 1 letter followed by a dot
- `([A-Za-z]+\.)?`: Optionally, at least 1 letter followed by a dot
- `[A-Za-z]+`: Match at least 1 letter
- `@email\.com`: Match `@email.com`

If you want to allow multiple middle initials, you can replace the `?` with `*`

If you want to allow numbers, replace the `A-Za-z` with `A-Za-z0-9`

In your validation rule (escaping the `\`):

```
!REGEX(Recipients__c, '[A-Za-z]+\\.([A-Za-z]+\\.)?[A-Za-z]+@email\\.com')
```